# Refresh section when using partialview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have `_Layout.cshtml`, the content is :

```
...
@RenderSection("MyTitle", required: false)
<div class="innerLR">
    <div id="appContent">
    @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
...
```

When I start the application, I go to this action `Home/Index`, the view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new BaseModel { Title = "Testing"});
}
```

The View Index.cshtml :

```
@section MyTitle{ @Model.Title }
bla bla bla
```

At this time it's ok, I see the : *Testing + bla bla bla*.

Now I call `Home/SecondAction` via Ajax when I click on a link, the controller return a PartialView and diplay the content in `appContent` div.
I call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/SecondAction',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        $(#appContent).html(result);
    }
});
```

The action is :

```
public ActionResult SecondAction()
{
    return PartialView(new BaseModel { Title = "Other Title" });
}
```

The SecondAction.cshtml is :

```
@section MyTitle{ @Model.Title }
bla bla again
```

Here that's not work, I'd have any error but I can the text from the first action and not :

*Other Titla bla bla again*

To resume I'd like when I return a `PartialView` render a section from the `_Layout.cshtml`

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to update 2 different sections of your DOM after the AJAX call. Once possibility to achieve that is to have your controller action return the rendered result of 2 partials as JSON:

```
public ActionResult SecondAction()
{
    return Json(new
    {
        section1 = RenderPartialViewToString("_Partial1", null),
        section2 = RenderPartialViewToString("_Partial2", new BaseModel { Title = "Other Title" }),
    });
}
```

and your AJAX call could now look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/SecondAction',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result) {
        // TODO: you should of course wrap the contents of section 1 in a div with
        // id="section1" in your _Layout.cshtml
        $('#section1').html(result.section1);

        $('#appContent').html(result.section2);
    }
});
```

Now you are probably wondering where is the `RenderPartialViewToString` method coming from? It's coming from [`here`](https://gist.github.com/cassioeskelsen/831567). Or from [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243433/how-to-render-a-razor-view-to-a-string-in-asp-net-mvc-3) if you wish.

Comment: Thanks Darin and sorry for the "wake-up email" :)

Answer (score 0):

use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and look in the console for errors or Chrome web tools (hit F12 in chrome),

it should be `$('#appContent').html(result);`

make sure you have IndexPartial View

make sure this view is not using a masterpage/Layout

Comment: The result of my view for me is correct return me "bla bla again" and anything else. The #appContent is updated but not the section

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code deeply you are calling `SecondAction` in $.ajax ie: `url: 'Home/SecondAction'`. 
But your action method name is `IndexPartial` ie:

```
public ActionResult IndexPartial()
{
    return PartialView(new BaseModel { Title = "Other Title" });
}
```

Please change your $.ajax statement like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/IndexPartial',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        $(#appContent).html(result);
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Little mistake when I prepare this post. Let's me correct this. But it's not that the error.

Comment: Please show your error by using firebug because I didn't get your question.

Comment: There is no error in firebug, just the MyTitle section is not updated when I click on a link to go to the secondaction. On the first action the section is updated, on the second action not.

Comment: Please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string