# How can I test MVC Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing, tdd

My Page has following Hidden Field

```
<%= Html.Hidden("SessionId", Model.Form.UniqueSessionId) %>
```

My Controller

```
public class SomeController 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var somemode = new GetSomeModel();
        return View(somemodel);
    }
}
```

I wanna be able to test whether the view has the hidden field

```
protected SomeController controller;

protected void SetupController()
{
   controller = new SomeController()
}

[Test]
public void view_has_hidden_field_for_SessionId()
{
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsTrue(result.contains("<input type="hidden" id="SessionId" />"));
}
```

Question is: How can i render view as string? Any help?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate, but the answer can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243433/how-to-render-a-razor-view-to-a-string-in-asp-net-mvc-3.

Comment: To quote uncle Bob (Robert Martin): "With your eyes"

Comment: I think the question here is : do you really want to unit test a view.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this solution which has support for razor views and standard asp.net views:

[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

My other advice to you would be to use an html parser such as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) so that you can then query it to find your hidden field. This approach is better as testing for string.contains will make your tests brittle when you refactor your html.