# Razor - write something unencoded without using html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm looking for a way to write a value in my razor view, without encoding it, AND without using the Html Helper.

I'm rendering the view in a hybrid website, where I parse my View programmatically, like this:

```
 string html = "<html>@("Write something <strong>unencoded</strong>"</html>")
 html = Razor.Parse<TModel>(html, model);
```

So essentially, my html variable contains a template containing razor c# code. Because I am compiling my view like this, I have no access to the Html helper (the accepted answer in this post implies this is indeed the case: [How to render a Razor View to a string in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243433/how-to-render-a-razor-view-to-a-string-in-asp-net-mvc-3))

However, my html variable also contains a statement like this:

```
 @Html.Raw("<strong>This should be printed unencoded</strong>")
```

This does not work but gives "Html is not available in this context".

How can I achieve the same behavior? Using Response.Write gives the exact same error.

Are there any other ways?

Note: this is a hybrid website, containing both classic ASP webforms and some newer Web API and MVC stuff. The View I'm using is NOT accessed through conventional MVC ways.

Answer (score 1):

[HtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type of string should work for you.

> Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.

Sample with creating such string inline (normally you'd have such values in `Model` set by controler):

```
  @(new HtmlString("<strong>This should be printed unencoded</strong>"))
```

Comment: Reading that documentation, I assume you're right. However, printing this doesn't work: @(new HtmlString("<strong>this should be unencoded</strong>"))  and produces the HTML literally (meaning it was encoded)

Comment: I found a way around this. I updated my question. It's not perfect, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out, but this is the final solution (which works for me, but has some security implications, so do read on!)

Compile your view like this

```
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
config.EncodedStringFactory = new RawStringFactory();

var service = RazorEngineService.Create(config);
html = service.RunCompile(html, "templateNameInTheCache", null, model);
```

As you can see, I employed the `RawStringFactory` to make sure no HTML at all gets encoded. Of course, MVC automatically encodes HTML as a safety precaution, so doing this isn't very safe. **Only do this if you're 100% sure that all of the output in the entire Razor view is safe!**